# Validation rule on effective date is less than or equal 120 days from oldest date in file

Tags: apex, validation

I want to create a validation rule where Effective Date of Certification is less than or equal to 120 days from Oldest Date in file. I had tried a lot of validation rule but i am not getting the correct solution.

```
 IF(( Effective_Date_Certification__c  -  Oldest_Date_in_file__c) <=120,true,false)
```

Comment: Are you subtracting older date from a future date and if yes, you might want to convert date values into numbers first. IFF ((datevalue(effective)- datevalue(oldest))) <= 120

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that much clear, you can use examples to clarify question.

See the below VR

```
IF((Oldest_Date_in_file__c - Effective_Date_Certification__c ) <=120,true,false)
```

This VR will fire when effectivedate is less than or equal 120 days from oldestdate.
hope   Oldest_Date_in_file__c  and Effective_Date_Certification__c  are date fields if is not you have to use datevalue function

I hope this will help you. Please letus know your feedback

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer
IF( ( Oldest_Date_in_file__c  -  Effective_Date_Certification__c  )<=120  &&(Oldest_Date_in_file__c  >=  Effective_Date_Certification__c),false,true)